# MySQL database is dropped from time to time in docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I have two docker containers for my project. The first one is php container and the second one MySQL database.
I use docker compose because it's very simple. In my docker compose container I configure mysql and volumes. I installed it to dev server and time to time I faced with full deleting database in the container. It deletes not only tables but database as well. I don't understand the reason and I don't know why locally I don't have the same problems.
Could someone help my?

Docker compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: ${USER:-user}
        uid: ${UID:-1000}
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile
    container_name: farmers-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/app/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
      - ./docker/app/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=${XDEBUG_SERVER_NAME:-farmers}
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: client_host=${XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST:-172.17.0.1} client_port=${XDEBUG_STORM_PORT:-9003}
    networks:
      - farmers

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: farmers-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
    ports:
      - ${DOCKER_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - farmers

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: farmers-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "${DOCKER_WEB_PORT:-8000}:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - farmers

networks:
  farmers:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Comment: Did you find solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the newest mysql docker images? how about the storage spaces in your dev server? is it sufficient and is the databases dropping when it reach specific storage spaces?

Comment: I don't think mysql version is a reason of the issue. Production server should have mysql 5.7. The server also have storage spaces

Comment: Please use the comments functionality to ask further questions rather than posting as an answer.